# Reemplazar texto por imagen o otro texto en un foreach con un javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, foreach, blade

Tengo un foreach en blade que muestra un listado de productos

```
@foreach ($results['resultadoComparador'] as $result)
<div id="field_name" name="field_name" class="w-100 position-relative fix-resolution">ACA LA IMAGEN</div>

<div id="field_name2" name="field_name2" class="w-100 position-relative fix-resolution">ACA LA DESCRIPCION</div>
@endforeach
```

y tengo un ajax que obtiene de un api, la descripción y de otra el logo del producto... según el id del producto.

Este es el JavaScript que recupera el logo del producto según el ID que esta en el foreach

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready( function () {
      $.ajax({
              url: "https://midominio.com/api/logo/4651", --->>> ACA VA EL ID {{ $result['idProduct'] }}
              type: "GET",
              cache: true,
              dataType: "text",
              success: function(response){
                var fieldNameElement = document.getElementById('field_name');
        if (fieldNameElement)
        {fieldNameElement.innerHTML = '<img src="data:image/png;base64, '+response+'" alt="Test" width="150" height="150"/>';}
              }
            });
    });
</script>
```

este es el javascript que recupera la descripcion

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready( function () {
      $.ajax({
              url: "https://midominio.com/api/desc/4651", --->>> ACA VA EL ID {{ $result['idProduct'] }}
              type: "GET",
              cache: true,
              dataType: "text",
              success: function(response){
                var fieldNameElement = document.getElementById('field_name2');
        if (fieldNameElement)
        {fieldNameElement.innerHTML = response.DescripcionProducto;}
              }
            });
    });
</script>
```

lo que no entiendo es como mandar el {{ $result['idProduct'] }} al ajax... y que se ejecute la cantidad de veces que sea necesario, actualmente me envía por ejemplo colocando el id manualmente 4651... y me reemplaza pero solamente el primer resultado, los otros no.

Comment: `url:` es una `string`. Simplemente podrías concatenar el `id` y buscaría el `id` que tengas almacenado en una variable o en algún índice de un array. Podrías almacenar los `id` que necesitas buscar en un arreglo y luego hacer un bucle que realice la acción tantas veces como cantidad de índices tenga el `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno logré solucionarlo, a la final lo que hice fue, en el html

```
<div id="field_name{{ $result['id'] }"
```

generar un id dinámico con el número de ID del producto...

luego puse el foreach nuevamente en el javascript para que recorra las url

```
url: "https://midominio.com/api/logo/"+{{ $result['id'] }},
```

y finalmente reemplace el div con el id dinámico...

```
var fieldNameElement = document.getElementById("field_name{{ $result['id'] }}");
```

Misma solución para la descripción